# Detecting scrolling past edge of ScrollViewer

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

I am simply wondering if it is possible, and how, to detect if an element within a ScrollViewer has been dragged past the edge of the viewer.

For instance, by dragging an image more than is allowed, the image is automatically positioned back within the ScrollViewer, indicating that at least the backend knows that the image/scroll has been dragged past its boundary. What I would want to do is to also detect when the boundary is crossed and then perform an action, such as treating the user activity as a swipe and changing the displayed item to something else.

**XAML illustration**

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="detailImageScroll" ZoomMode="Enabled">
    <Image x:Name="detailImage" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**C# pseudocode illustration**

```
SomeScrollManipulationEvent()
{
  if detailImage.left < detailImageScroll.left
    GoToPreviousImage()
  else if detailImage.right > detailImageScroll.right
    GoToNextImage()
}
```

What I have come up with so far is that manipulations is not possible within ScrollViewers nor its images, at least not without losing the functionality of the ScrollViewer, e.g. zooming and panning.

*Is it event possible for me to implement the proposed functionality? If so, how?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually built into the platform. Check the [`HorizontalSnapPointsType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalsnappointstype.aspx) and [`HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalsnappointsalignment.aspx) properties.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to me that the snap-points are used instead of manual panning a ScrollView, to snap the view into positions showing appropriate content. Will they still work for a single item (e.g. an image) within a ScrollViewer?

To clarify, I would want to receive an event (or other design pattern) to run custom code whenever the user pans the image past the bounds of the ScrollViewer. In my case, I am looking for a way to display a pannable and zoomable image, that when panned "too much" to either left or right, lets me programmatically switch image to something appropriate.

Comment: You can put your `ScrollViewer` into a `FlipView`. That would work the way you describe.